# How to spot mistake in code (TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable)?

Tags: python, typeerror

```
block = [(1, 2), (6, 6), (8, 10), (13, 14)]

def add_line(block, y):
    added_line = []
    for (x1, x2) in block:
        added_line += zip((x1, x2), y)

    return added_line
```

It is supposed to add y to (x1, x2) tuple. Instead it produces TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. What did I do wrong and where?

Comment: Are you calling *add_line* with an integer as the 2nd parameter? You should probably show how you're calling the function and what output you're expecting. You say you want to add something to a tuple. Are you aware that tuples are immutable?

Comment: Please make a [mre] including complete code and the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). There are multiple points of iteration here, and it's not clear what arguments are being passed to the function, so there are multiple places where that TypeError could occur. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you provide an `int` object(`y`) in the zip function. zip function takes iterable objects.

You can do this

```
block = [(1, 2), (6, 6), (8, 10), (13, 14)]

def add_line(block, y):
    added_line = []
    for (x1, x2) in block:
        added_line += ((x1, x2, y),)

    return added_line
```

Or try this

```
block = [(1, 2), (6, 6), (8, 10), (13, 14)]

def add_line(block, y):
    added_line = []
    for cor in block:
        added_line += ((*cor, y),)

    return added_line
```

Comment: Are you sure that's what OP wants?

Answer (score 0):

This is my interpretation of "It is supposed to add y to (x1, x2) tuple"

```
block = [(1, 2), (6, 6), (8, 10), (13, 14)]

def add_line(block, y):
    return [(*t, y) for t in block]

print(add_line(block, 9))
```

**Output:**

```
[(1, 2, 9), (6, 6, 9), (8, 10, 9), (13, 14, 9)]
```